# Function which will print the minimum number of letters that can appear in a list of words

Tags: dart, logic

I need a dart function which will print the minimum number of letters which can be present in all the given words. Suppose the words are "apple, table, rum, bread". The function should print "a" and "r". Let me explain how. As you can see three words (apple, table, bread) have common letters (a, e), the function should either print a or e. On the other hand the "rum" have no letters which are common among the other words letters so the function should either print "r" or "u" or "m". Please do let me know if you need any further explanation. Thank you

Tried the below code but it is printing "No common letters."

```
void findCommonLetters(List<String> words) {
      if (words.isEmpty) {
        print("No common letters.");
        return;
      }
    
      Set<String> commonLetters = Set.from(words[0].split(''));
    
      for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        final word = words[i];
        final wordLetters = Set.from(word.split(''));
    
        commonLetters = commonLetters.intersection(wordLetters);
      }
    
      if (commonLetters.isEmpty) {
        print("No common letters.");
      } else {
        print("Common letters: ${commonLetters.join(", ")}");
      }
    }
    
    void main() {
      List<String> words = ["apple", "banana", "sun"];
      findCommonLetters(words);
    }
```

Comment: You want some sort of "minimum cover". You have the set of letters occurring in the words, and the set of words, and connections between the letters and the words they occur in. That's a "bipartite graph", so there might be some related graph algorithm you can use - but not one I can remember. It's a place to start looking.

Comment: Well I had created an algorithm and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function is not doing what you expect it to. There are no common letters between apple, banana AND sun. And this is what you are checking

The value of `commonLetters` changes as follows:

```dart
// before the loop
['a','p','l','e']
// in the first loop iteration, ['a','p','l','e'] intersected with ['b','a','n']
['a']
// in the second loop iteration, ['a'] intersected with ['s','u','n']
[]
```

In your original example, `['apple', 'table', 'bread']` your function works perfectly: it prints

```
Common letters: a, e
```

### Comparing all words

If instead you want to look at the common letters between every combination of words in the set, you can try looping over each pair and comparing them there.

```dart
void findCommonLetters(List<String> words) {
  if (words.isEmpty) {
    print("No common letters.");
    return;
  }
  
  Set<String> commonLetters = {};
  for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    Set<String> iLetters = Set.from(words[i].split(''));
    // we only need to compare 1 way, so we can start at i+1
    for (int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++) {
      Set<String> jLetters = Set.from(words[j].split(''));
      
      // compare word i and word j, and store their common letters
      commonLetters.addAll(iLetters.intersection(jLetters).toList());
    }
  }
  
  if (commonLetters.isEmpty) {
    print("No common letters.");
  } else {
    print("Common letters: ${commonLetters.join(", ")}");
  }
}

void main() {
  List<String> words = ["apple", "banana", "sun"];
  findCommonLetters(words);
}
```

So the question is, what do you expect? If you want to find the common letters between *all* words in a set, congratulations, you already did it :p

Otherwise, you can look at the code above to compare *every pair* of words in the set. For `['apple', 'table', 'bread']`, this would return

```
Common letters: a, l, e, b
```

And for `["apple", "banana", "sun"]` this would return

```
Common letters: a, n
```

Comment: No this is not what i want. suppose the words are "slip, rum, cat" then the function should return any letter from each word as there are no common letters in all the words. if the words are "sleep, grow, team"then function should return "e" and any letter from grow. why? because as you can see that e is common between sleep and if there a word have no common letters with other words then any letter from that word should be returned. does it make sense?